# What is series coefficient for $f(x)=\csc^2 x - \frac1{x^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

What is general formula for Maclauren series expansion for $f(x)=\csc^2 x - \frac1{x^2}$ ?

Comment: What can we start with, is a partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}$ something that is within scope?

Answer (score 2):

Start from $\int \csc^2(x) dx=-\cot(x)$ and the known expansion for the cotangent in terms of Bernoulli numbers $B(2n),$ namely
$$\cot x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n2^{2n}B_{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}.$$
So change the sign of this and find its derivative. Then the term from $n=0$ becomes the $1/x^2$ term which you have already subtracted, and I get for each $n\ge 1$ a coefficient for $x^{2n-2}$ of
$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}2^{2n}B_{2n}(2n-1)}{(2n)!},$$
which checks out via the first few $n$ with another method via the usual use of derivatives to get a taylor series, with need for LHopital for some limits.

Comment: I already found the answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699611/why-this-function-is-elementary-and-its-pair-is-not#comment1467376_699611

Comment: @Anixx The linked article in your comment is equivalent to the expansion of my answer, given the known explicit formula for $\zeta(2k).$

Comment: it seemed to me that your answer was not finished because it ended with a comma.

Comment: @Anixx That comma at the end would better be a period, and I was only saying I had checked by another way that the first few coefficients $1/3,1/15,2/189$ from the complicated formula were right. [will fix the comma]

Answer (score 0):

I already found the answer myself, the expansion is

$$f(x)=\frac{2 \zeta (2)}{\pi ^2}+\frac{6 \zeta(4) x^2}{\pi^4}+\frac{10 \zeta(6) x^4}{\pi^6}+\frac{14 \zeta(8) x^6}{\pi^8}+\cdots$$